# QGIS cannot open my project

Tags: qgis

I can't open my project, when I try to Open QGIS it was like "Python error"
and when QGIS is open there was `"Authentication System: DISABLED. Resources authenticating via the system can not be accessed"`.

Then I try to open project it wrote that `"There are still 4 unhandled layer(s), that will be lost if you closed now."` I use Windows 10.

Comment: If you [Work with a New User Profile](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#working-with-user-profiles), are all the errors solved?

Comment: Do you load any layers of the internet or layers from a local server that need an authentication in that project?